# How to set a new value to the textfield inside the UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Does this code triggers when I call [Self.table reloadData]

```
if (cell == nil){...}
```

Im wondering because I have added a UITextField in the cell:

```
//cellForRowAtIndexPath
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        recepientTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.origin.x+40, 10, 469, 20)];
        [cell addSubview:recepientTextField];
    }
    recepientTextField.text = recipient;
    return cell;
```

Then I download some stuff from internet and I then want to show the info in `recepientTextField.text` in the TableView. So I call set a new value to `recipient` variable and then `[self.tableView realoadData]` But it crashes. I think it has to do with the textfields allocation. How can I fix this? How can I change the text afterwards?

Comment: What does the stack trace for the crash look like?

Comment: Include the error message in question

Comment: 0x18aa09b:  movl   8(%edx), %edi 
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACESS (code=1, adress=0x....)

Comment: I dont get any information about the line! It just opens the Debug Navigator in the left sidebar.

Comment: Include the full code

Comment: Well of course it will crash, if `cell != nil`, your `recipientTextField` won't be allocated and then when you try to set its `text` property, you will get a bad access because there is no such thing. Cel != nil when the tableview is reusing the cells.

Comment: I have updated the original post. How can I do this the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reloaded the `cell != nil` case comes and there the `recipientTextField` has null reference and hence the crash

Try this

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    recepientTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.origin.x+40, 10, 469, 20)];
    [recepientTextField setTag:333];
    [cell addSubview:recepientTextField];
}

UITextField *TF=(UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:333];
TF.text = recipient;
return cell;
```